# In what circumstances IF statement can trigger the command in condition line?

Tags: php, if-statement

Let say I have this code:

```
$conn=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO login (username, password)
VALUES ('$username','$password')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

In second IF statement I checked out if $conn->query($sql) === TRUE. This code works although I didn't previously execute $conn->query($sql). In this IF statement, PHP executes the command and checks out if it is executed at the same time.
 What if I only want to check not execute? In what circumstances you can execute a command in IF statement and in what you only check if it is previously done.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand - if you only want its first value simply just save its result to a variable and use that instead. There's no way for you to get the result of an expression (eg. a function or a method in this case) without executing the function or method. It simply has to run through the code the method was meant to do. You _could_ begin a database transaction and later revert the transaction if it fails but why would you in this case? If you're only inserting one object, and it fails to get inserted you don't need to do anything else with it.

Comment: I wanted to ask shouldn't it be $conn->query($sql); if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

Comment: No, you should save the result to a variable if you want to do a check like this. `$result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result) ...`